# How to install selenium with python 3 ananconda on windows?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, anaconda, python-3.6

I am trying to installing selenium with anaconda but failed.I also tried the command " conda install selenium " but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to conda install packages the package must be hosted on anaconda.org. There is no package called simply "selenium" in the default anaconda channel. There is a package in the conda-forge channel however and it can be installed using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

Read more about it here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium